# How to make a blob invert its direction in the fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

This code makes a blob object to go up in the y axis and it's supposed to invert its direction when it reaches the center of the screen.

The blob object goes up, but it disappears when it reaches the center of the screen.

```c
uniform float   uTime;
varying vec2 vXY;   
    
void main(void) {   
    vec2 uBlob = vec2(0.0, -5.0);
    float direction = 1.;

    float blobPos = uBlob.y + direction*(uTime/1000.); 
    if (blobPos > 0.0) {
        direction *= -1.0; // Reverse direction
    }
    uBlob.y += (direction*(uTime/1000.)); 

    vec4 color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    float dist2 = pow((vXY.x - uBlob.x), 2.0) + pow((vXY.y - uBlob.y), 2.0);

    vec3 fImplicit = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    fImplicit.r = (1.0 / dist2); //this creates the red blob

    color = vec4(fImplicit.r, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

The code produces this image:

[image]

The red circle keeps going upward until it reaches the center of the screen then it disappears. What is going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the way you're computing `uBlob.y` : if the blob doesn't go further than 0, `uBlob.y = -5.0 + uTime/1000.;`. If thats not the case then `uBlob.y = -5.0 - uTime/1000.;`. That means that when `uTime/1000` becomes greater than `5.0` the blob will teleport to -10.0 and its position will continue to decrease. To solve this, you can replace this :

```
if (blobPos > 0.0) {
    direction *= -1.0; // Reverse direction
}
```

by this :

```
if (blobPos > 0.0) {
    direction *= -1.0; // Reverse direction
    uBlob.y = 0.0 + 5.0 // 0.0 is the point where the blob is reflected and 5.0 is the distance it already travelled
}
```